# ¿Cómo invocar la función e imprimir el valor de la variable en php?

Tags: php, funciones, variables, parametros, variables-globales

nuevamente pido su ayuda para orientación en estos ejercicios, ahora es sobre funciones en php, sobre el tema scopes (Parámetros por default y paso de argumentos por referencia) ya investigue pero aun no me queda claro el tema y también tengo duda si estoy realizando bien los ejercicios. Lo que quiero realizar es el punto 4 del ejercicio invocar la función, que es lo me confunde un poco.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//Ejercicio: Paso de argumentos por referencia.
$a = "Global";

function modifyGlobal($b){
    $b = "Modificado dentro la función";
}
modifyGlobal($b);
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: Explica mas el contexto de este código, ¿qué salida te da, que error?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? ¿Qué problemas o errores hay en tu código? En la pregunta hablas de *pasar por referencia*, pero eso no ocurre en ningún caso. El enunciado del ejercicio tampoco te indica que pases parámetros por referencia ... Luego, hay una función `cubo()` de la cual no dices nada. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta indicando claramente y concretamente cuál es el problema.

Comment: dependiendo del lenguaje de programación generalmente las variables que se definen dentro de una función sólo existen dentro de la función, el scope ( ámbito, alcance, contexto ) se dice que es local. variables que están por fuera de la función se les llaman globales, también dependiendo del lenguaje de programación las variables globales pueden no estar disponibles dentro de las funciones, es el caso de php donde para acceder a una variable global y poder cambiarla se usa la palabra [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Segui las instrucciones:
1- imprime b (un echo)
2- asigna a b = "Modificado ..."
3- retorna b
4- invoca la funcion (ejecutarla)
5- Imprime a (echo), nada tiene que ver con tu funcion a